Text extraction from pdf tables - differentiating between columns & rows
I'm using 'Fitz' library to extract text from a pdf file. Bounding boxes/rectangles will be drawn around tables from which text is supposed to be extracted.
The current extraction is returning the text row-wise, i.e., first all the columns are being listed & then the rows.
Eg: col1 col2 col3 row1col1_val row1col2_val row1col3_val row2col1_val row2col2_val row2col3_val row3col1_val row3col2_val row3col3_val.
# # TEXT EXTRACTED FROM BOUNDING BOX
import fitz

def extract_text_from_bounding_box(pdf_file, coordinates):
  # Open the PDF file
  pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_file)
  
  # Initialize an empty string to store the extracted text
  extracted_text = ""
  
  # Iterate through each bounding box coordinates
  for coord in coordinates:
    # Extract coordinates
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(float, coord.split(','))
  
    # Create a rectangle based on coordinates
    rect = fitz.Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2)
  
    # Iterate through each page in the PDF
    for page_number in range(len(pdf_document)):
      page = pdf_document[page_number]
  
      # Extract text from the specified rectangle
      text = page.get_text("text", clip=rect)
  
      # Append extracted text to the result
      extracted_text += text
  
  # Close the PDF document
  pdf_document.close()
  
  return extracted_text

I want the output to be interpretable. The person reading the extracted text should be able to know what value corresponds to what column.
Some differentiation factors I've thought of:

Vertical Spacing of 'Column headers'. The width of columns tends to be larger for the columns compared to the rows.
'Font Size' of columns could be different.

The above assumptions may not hold true in all cases. Can you suggest me a better solution?

Why don't you use PyMuPDF's table extraction page.find_tables()?

This is giving me the error: AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'get_tables'. I tried reinstalling & upgrading. Nothing works. My PyMuPDF version is: 1.24.1.

look again: find_tables!!!
